# parse-server session gets deleted

Tags: ios, parse-server

Our app (parseSDK 1.13) has a parse-server (2.2.15) backend and sometimes (reproduceable) the user's session gets destroyed. After loading some custom objects from parse-server, the app (or more precise: parse-SDK) sends a strange request to parse-server to set the user password while i'm not doing any register/login/pw-reset related action:

Request: POST /parse/batch

```
{"requests": [{
    "path": "\/parse\/classes\/_User\/abcu45BFAd",
    "method": "PUT",
    "body": {
        "password": "xyz"
    }
}]}
```

Response:

```
 [{
      "success": {
        "updatedAt": "2016-07-05T23:04:51.041Z"
      }
  }]
```

After that request, the server completely destroys the Session entry in the database without any notice. All following requests fail with error 209 (invalid session token).
I do not intent to set/update the pssword and i cannot find, where this request comes from. Any hints are highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed with upcoming 2.2.17